# Evaluating code in the context of an instance with the shikashi gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
require 'shikashi'

class EvalContext
  def get_binding
    binding
  end

  def a_method
    puts 'test ok'
  end
end

eval_context = EvalContext.new
eval_context.get_binding.eval('a_method') # => test ok

sandbox = Shikashi::Sandbox.new
privileges = Shikashi::Privileges.new
privileges.allow_method(:a_method)

sandbox.run('a_method', privileges: privileges, binding: eval_context.get_binding)
# => in 'handle_method': Cannot invoke method method_missing on object of class BasicObject (SecurityError)
sandbox.run('a_method', privileges: privileges, base_namespace: eval_context)
# => in `rescue in packet': SyntaxError (SyntaxError)
```

What I am exactly missing?

Answer (score -2):

not sure about this shikashi gem, but what you are trying to do doesn't work that way.

Binding returns the current binding. So since you're calling it inside of your EvalContext, you are getting the binding for the EvalContext, not the sandbox

I'm going to answer the question you asked, even though I don't recommend these solutions:

You need to either monkypatch that class to add the method

```
# Be very careful monkey-patching classes this way!
class Sandbox
  def get_binding
     binding
  end
end
```

Or do send the binding method into to be run inside of the sandbox instance

```
sandbox.send(:eval, "binding") # Be very careful using the send method!
```

Maybe if you give us an idea on what you're trying to do, we can recommend a better idea

Comment: I want the binding of the EvalContext precisely... I want to evaluate the code with the Sandbox inside the EvalContext instance.

Comment: Then you should look at : https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-eval

You can do something like: eval("code", get_binding)

Comment: If I use Kernel#eval there is not sandbox.. is this some kind of joke?

Comment: Only to those who can't see the obvious similarity between something these 2 lines:

1. sandbox.run('a_method', privileges: privileges, binding: eval_context.get_binding)

2. eval("sandbox.run('a_method', privileges: privileges)", eval_context.get_binding)